Fantasy Medieval Movie with possession
I am trying to find an old medieval/horror/ fantasy movie I watched in my youth. The movie is about a guy who is possessed by a demon, spirit .. don't know exactly. He comes to a fishermans village and was invited into a house by it's family. ... afterwards he gets possessed and kills the whole family.
After this a chubby monk tries to find out about the murder and uses some magic spell which displays the murderer (he uses sand or dust as far as I can recall).
I also remember that the monk and the possessed one travel together to get rid of the curse of possession.
They get to an isle with I think was a dragon.
In the end the man fights against his demon, spirit, monster.
It was an real life movie and coloured. I do not know in which country this movie was produced. I watched this movie i assume between the years 2000-2007. Movie was in english.
Does anyone have an idea which movie this could be?

Welcome to Movies.SE! We have a minimum requirement for ID questions on this site. Do you remember when/where/how you watched this movie? What language was it in? Was it an American production, or from a different country? Was it real life or animated? Was it in color? We'll need answers to these questions to help us track down an answer to this question.  If you have this information, please edit it into your question.

by real life movie did you mean a live action movie?
